# How should I query in SQL for three metrics a, b, c and verify that they satisfy (a + b)/2 = c？

Tags: mysql, sql

I now want to query the three indicators a, b, and c in the database, and verify whether the formula (a + b) / 2 = c holds. what should I do? I can only query a, b and c now

```
select
    a,
    b,
    c
from
    table_test
where
    type = 1
    and
    origin not in (10, 20)
```

Comment: Do you want to check only? Or you want this checking always to be TRUE and does not allow to insert inconsistent data into your table (for all rows or for some rows which matches some additional conditions)?

Comment: What is type and origin ?  Please either remove them from your trial or explain the whole thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the assertion in the `WHERE` clause:

```sql
SELECT a, b, c, IF((a + b) / 2 = c, 'True', 'False') AS result
FROM table_test
WHERE type = 1 AND origin NOT IN (10, 20) AND
      (a + b) / 2 = c;   -- added condition here
```

Comment: I see, thank you. Is there any solutions that can show me True or False? For example, show True when (a + b) / 2 = c?

Comment: @YuboLiang Check the updated answer.